# How to test javascript and Groovy in one Gradle Project

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, gradle, groovy, jacoco

I have a situation where I am trying to test Groovy and Javascript in same project.

Following are my folder structure

All the source script available in below folder
src/main/javascript
src/main/groovy

All the Test script available in below folder
src/test/javascript
src/test/groovy

Currently I am able to include all the groovy classes using build.gradle

> sourceSets {
> main {
> groovy {
> srcDirs = ['data/forgerock-idm/main/data/script']
> }
> }

Also for testing I am using Spock framework for groovy.

testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:2.4-M1-groovy-3.0'

I am unable to find a way to include javascript folder in this sourceSets. Please let me know how to achieve this so all the javascript will also be include in Jacoco code coverage report. Test classes I have written in Groovy.

Comment: Jacoco is only used for Java/JVM based code.  It wouldn't work for Javascript unless you're running that javascript inside the JVM  using the GralalVM.  And even then I"m not sure Jacoco could measure and display things in the actual javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there any code coverage report plugins like Jacoco for Javascript available which can be integrated with Gradle project. Please let me know. I tried with JSCover but not working .

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jest.js as your testing tool for Javascript it'll collect code [coverage statistics](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#collectcoverage-boolean) for you.  You can then export that in various formats like text, json, clover, cobratura, etc.

In order to do this in Gradle you'll need an npm plugin for gradle, and a multi-project gradle setup.

Your top level project would consist of a directory for your Groovy project, and another directory for your Javascript project.  The root directory will house the `build.gradle` for the multi-project, and a `settings.gradle` will include the projects from the Groovy project directory, and the Javascript project directory.  Each of those directories will contain a `build.gradle` file.  See Gradle's discussion on [Multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).

You'll add the Jacoco plugin to your Groovy project's `build.gradle` file then add an [npm plugin](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin) to the javascript `build.gradle` and create the structure to control the npm build from within Gradle.  Then you can invoke the javascript build from within Gradle, and that should execute Jest thus running your code coverage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How we can configure JEST in Gradle to test javascripts. I tried but it is not working, if you have any example for the build.gradle file where all the dependencies, plugins are listed. Please help me.